# FileReader API: viewing the contents outside of a callback

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I've been using the FileReader API to read local files and feed them to a Java applet, and this has worked for now. The file gets read, the applet behaves like it's supposed to. The function which passes the contents of the file (as String) to the applet is currently called INSIDE the function assigned to the onloadend() event of the Reader (I use onloadend() insteat than onload() for some error handling needs. Though maybe I could replace that with a try/catch instruction, I'll look into it). Now I'd like to pass the contents of the file to a global variable, in order to parse it with Javascript as well. The problem is that this seems to be impossible, because:

1) the .result member of the FileReader object after the file has been loaded is empty (and this makes sense, seeing how the reader itself is asynchronous);

2) if I copy the .result member into a global variable, e.g. if I do:

```
var my_string;

function load_callback()
{
   //Do some stuff...
   my_string = this.result;
}

...

my_reader = new FileReader();
my_reader.onloadend = load_callback;
my_reader.readAsText(my_file)
document.getElementById("empty_paragraph").innerHTML = my_string;
```

I get a big nice `undefined` as a result (and this does not make much sense, really).
What should I do? Is this some other security feature, making it impossible for FileReader to propagate the contents of a file outside of its callback methods? Before anyone mentions it - yes, the file has been properly submitted by the user (as I said, the rest of the page works); yes, I have checked that the name `my_string` is not duplicated in any way; and I've tested this on both Chromium and Firefox, so it's not browser-dependent. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous file readers are only available in WebWorker context, because blocking a worker thread doesn't cause the UI to freeze. Anyway, there is **no way to view the contents outside of a callback, unless** you use:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

Which only works in firefox. It allows you to use the `yield` keyword, which can be used to implement [fibers](http://taskjs.org/) that can be used to write asynchronous code in synchronous way.

Comment: As I said, however, the problem is only a time one... once the file has been read, I can access its contents freely (through the global variable, of course).

Comment: @Okarin Yea, because accessing variables is synchronous. FileReader is asynchronous, so the initial read is *impossible* without callbacks. It is not a security feature but a feature that allows you to do I/O in the same thread without blocking.

Comment: Yes, I understand that much. The answer above yours was deleted, but the essence was that the thing works - I only have to give it enough time for the file to be actually read. I'll try to find a better workaround (just putting a wait would be a horrid solution, and a machine dependent one at it), but at least I know that - in principle - it's not impossible.

Comment: @Okarin yes it it impossible because the only way to wait is to use something else asynchronous, which also requires a callback and so on. Trust me, it's impossible. In case you were thinking of a busy loop `(while !reader.hasResult)` then that will not work either because the loop prevents the event for reading file to be dispatched, so it will never get to have a result and thus the loop is infinite.